# Non, pas, non pas

Tags: choix-de-mot, négation, incises

Dans la phrase

> La singularité de chaque soldat, pas leur identité, est dissoute.

peut-on interchanger *pas* avec *non* ou *non pas* ?

Quel est le plus correct ?

> La singularité de chaque soldat, pas leur identité, est dissoute.
>
> La singularité de chaque soldat, non leur identité, est dissoute.
>
> La singularité de chaque soldat, non pas leur identité, est dissoute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Les trois possibilités sont correctes, chacune dans leur contexte propre. Les deux premières possibilités diffèrent par leur [registre de langue](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais) : la première est commune, fréquente à l'oral, la seconde est plus soutenue, plus littéraire.

La dernière possibilité renforce la négation, et suggère un contexte d'argumentation. Par exemple :

> — L'identité de chaque soldat est ainsi dissoute.
>   — C'est la singularité de chaque soldat, *non pas* leur identité, qui est dissoute.